# How to cut a chord from a circle in Sketch App

Tags: sketch-app

I have a circle that I want to cut several lines horizontal lines from so I can see the background.

As you can see from my image below, I want to cut out the part of the circle so I can see the background.

[image]

How do I cut this out? It must be a transparent gap, not a piece of black color because the round shape will be placed on different backgrounds as SVG file.

Comment: But it won't be transparent. I want to use it on a website as an SVG so I can see what's behind it. How can I make those rectangles transparent?

Comment: I removed the comment and inserted the transparency demand to the question. I guess (not tried) boolean subtraction spoils the gradient fill. https://www.sketch.com/docs/shapes/boolean-operations/

Comment: jow about clipping mask?

Comment: @joojaa how do I do that? Looks like the docs are incomplete https://developer.sketch.com/reference/action/clippingmask/

Comment: I guess most of us would find the solution by making a few experiments if the needed functionality is implemented. But most of us haven't purchased Sketch and even cannot try it due the platform limitation. It's Mac only. While waiting some real Sketch user reads the question and bothers to answer you maybe can get Inkscape and apply there Path > Subtract. See this screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvc4hd7elk91dgk/Subtract_Inkscape.jpg?dl=0 The same can work in Sketch, too. Or it doesn't, because you ask.

Comment: @user287001 Found Sketch also has path subtract function. That did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the subtract layer option in Sketch (Layer -> Combine -> Subtract). You can create a group of rectangles that are in the position where you would like the "empty" space in your circle. Place the group over the circle and select both the rectangle group and the circle and select the subtract option at the top. Now you can export the circle and you can place it over any color background.[image: sketch-example-image]